# Android Programmatically adding the textview

Tags: android, xml, dynamic, textview, android-scrollview

so from debugging and commenting out things i have come to the conclusion that the problem from this program is in the addTextView() method. I have absolutely no idea where the problem is going wrong. My guess is in the layout that i am trying to add to the TextView. 
thanks you so much in advance for your help.

```
public class Books extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.books);
        addTextView("Hello World");
    }


    public void addTextView(String text)
    {
        ScrollView viewport = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.books);
        TextView textview= (TextView)new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(text);
        //textview.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        viewport.addView(textview, new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    public void addButton(String text)
    {
        ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.books);
        Button btnTag = (Button)new Button(Books.this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText(text);
        scrollview.addView(btnTag);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors.

Comment: You might consider storing the ScrollView as a field, then all your references to it will be using the same name (which would help keep your Activity easy to read) and will be wasting less memory.

Comment: okay, i thought this was a valid question i don't know why they closed it. Thank god ataulm was a genius and understood it perfectly. It's a real shame because others will be confused by this and would have benefit from the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ScrollViews can only have one child, typically a LinearLayout. When you call `scrollview.addView(blah blah)` you're adding more children to the ScrollView which is not allowed.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) for documentation about ScrollView.

--

On a side note, when posting questions on StackOverflow about errors you encounter, please state:

- the **error** you encounter (in Android, this'll be found in the LogCat view)
- your expected results (what you were trying to do)
- the relevant code (in this case, you should include your layout XML file too - while the ScrollView error is definitely *one* of the errors you'll get, it might not be the first one that needs fixing, in order to move forward).

It'll help everyone, including people in future who stumble upon this question.

Comment: Thanks so much you helped alot. and thanks for taking the time to explain how to use the website better rather than just complaining. Happy holidays

Comment: you're welcome, you too.